# How to remove wrinkles to ease ironing

Tags: clothing, efficiency

What is best way to iron clothes with so much wrinkles? I find it’s so hard to iron. What are ways to make ironing easy?
[image: wrinkles clothes]

Answer (score 5):

*An ounce of prevention is worth a pound of cure.*

**1. Prevention**

Looking at this fabric, these wrinkles have been “created”, either by putting the fabric in a dryer (probably also letting the warm dry laundry sit in the dryer until cold) or by drying the fabric just as it came out of the washing machine.

The first step when you are dealing with wrinkle-prone fabric is making sure that you minimize the amount of wrinkles that happen in the laundry steps prior to ironing.

If you have the option to line-dry (which I personally would recommend here), shake the piece of cloth well, smooth out the fabric and hang it so that it is as smooth as possible.
If you must use a dryer, use a low temperature setting and do not over dry, ideally take it out when it’s just a bit damp and iron straight away. In any case, take it out while it’s still warm and smooth it out. Also check the manual, some dryers have special settings.

**2. Ironing**

When you are working with this level of wrinkles, you want to use steam. If you have a steam iron, follow the instructions. Alternatively (or actually in any case), make your laundry very slightly damp. You can mist it - some people prefer a spray bottle, in a pinch, grab a small bowl with water, dip your fingers in it and sprinkle it on the fabric. (Pro tip: roll up the piece and wait a few minutes, so that the humidity can even out throughout the fabric.) Iron, problem solved.

———

Note: I am assuming that you know how to hold/strech the fabric with one hand while moving the iron with the other? If not, that would be very much a “how-to” question and probably off-topic.

Comment: Thank you for the ideas and why it is happening. I noticed that clothes shrunk when I use heated dryer, hence I go for line dryer. I hate to strech and hold on many wrinkles as ironing on such cloth cause more iron wrinkles.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot clearly see what type of item this is, but first I would contemplate if this even needs ironing. If it's something like a bed sheet or underwear, I wouldn't invest the time to iron it.

If it is an upper garment or pair of pants, there are ironing machines that can help you. I use one of them and didn't have to manually iron any shirt since. Here's an example:

[image]

It's basically a thin fabric sack formed like legs or a torso. You dress it like a doll with a wet garment, activate the machine and it blows up with hot air. In my experience you only have to run the machine for a minute for each garment. That doesn't entirely dry the garment, but it's enough to remove the creases. I transfer each garment to a coat hanger and hang them from the frame of my drying rack until they're completely dry.

**The disadvantages**: You have to put every single garment on the machine when it's still wet from the washing machine. The machine is a little bulky and requires storage space and a power outlet within reach.

**The advantages**: It takes some time to put garments on and off again, but certainly a lot less time than ironing each item. If you urgently need an item, you can get it from just-washed and wet to ready-to-wear (dry and wrinkle free) in a few minutes.